# Using Required field optionally with ASP.NET MVC Data Annotation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, data-annotations

I use EF Data Annotations in an ASP.NET MVC project and for the mandatory fields I define the fields as shown below:

***Model:***

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required!");
public string PhoneHome{ get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required!");
public string PhoneWork{ get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required!");
public string PhoneMobile { get; set; }
```

***View:***

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhoneHome)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PhoneHome, null, new { @class = "field-validation-error" })

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhoneWork)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PhoneWork, null, new { @class = "field-validation-error" })

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhoneMobile )
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PhoneMobile , null, new { @class = "field-validation-error" })
```

I want to make only one of these fields mandatory (if the user fill one of these fields it is ok, but if he does not fill any of them I want to display an error message and do not let he to submit form), but have no idea about the most suitable and smarter approach to perform this? Should I check all of these fields using JavaScript on submit and display necessary error message? Or should I perform this by using the Data Annotations only?

Comment: To clarify, you're already aware of the solution but you're just conflicted if you want to validate on the UI or on Server side?

Comment: I think you are best of creating your own validation rule based on the `Required` attribute but with some extra parameters and extra validation logic. This will validate on the server side but you can easily implement it on the client side.

Comment: @JerdineSabio Actually this does not solve the problem, because if I use this approach the user is not allowed to fill just one field and left blank the other two field. But I want to let the user to fill at least one field. Am I wrong?

Comment: @lordvlad30 I used `ExpressiveAnnotations` some years ago. In this scene do you mean that using `ExpressiveAnnotations` on server side and make necessary updates on client side using Javascript?

Comment: @hexadecimal I would create your own attribute extending `ValidationAttribute` (`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`) and to support client side validation you need to implement the `IClientValidatable` interface (`System.Web.Mvc`). But if you only need it once I would probably not put to much work into it and just validate it in the controller before checking the `ModelState.IsValid`.

Comment: The standard data annotations won’t be able to validate this requirement. So you will have to add custom validation logic (both on the server and on the client). – As an alternative to that: Do you actually care what kind of phone number a user enters? If you just want _any_ phone number, you could just ask for a single phone number, regardless of the kind it is. That way you reduce the inputs the user has to look at and greatly reduce the validation complexity.

Comment: @lordvlad30 I agree with you. But in order to set the validation on the model as the other properties, I would like to use the approach using `IValidatableObject`. So, why do not you post an answer by using `IValidatableObject`? Thanks in advance...

Comment: @poke Actually in most cases I would need to validate format besides empty field for a phone number. So, in this case it would be better to fix this in the model. If I use custom validation logic on the model as WebMaster suggested, do I also need extra validation on the client side? Coulad you post an example pls for server and client side? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I made an example. I create a custom validation attribute that has some parameters like what properties are required and how many (minimum and maximum). The naming is not the best but it does the job (not tested). You can remove the ICientValidatable if you do not care about valdiation on the client (using jquery validation, unobstrusive ...).

The attribute is made like this:

```
public class OptionalRequired : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The name of the client validation rule
    /// </summary>
    private readonly string type = "optionalrequired";

    /// <summary>
    /// The (minimum) amount of properties that are required to be filled in. Use -1 when there is no minimum. Default 1.
    /// </summary>
    public int MinimumAmount { get; set; } = 1;
    /// <summary>
    /// The maximum amount of properties that need to be filled in. Use -1 when there is no maximum. Default -1.
    /// </summary>
    public int MaximumAmount { get; set; } = -1;

    /// <summary>
    /// The collection of property names
    /// </summary>
    public string[] Properties { get; set; }


    public OptionalRequired(string[] properties)
    {
        Properties = properties;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        int validPropertyValues = 0;

        // Iterate the properties in the collection
        foreach (var propertyName in Properties)
        {
            // Find the property
            var property = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(propertyName);

            // When the property is not found throw an exception
            if (property == null)
                throw new ArgumentException($"Property {propertyName} not found.");

            // Get the value of the property
            var propertyValue = property.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance);

            // When the value is not null and not empty (very simple validation)
            if (propertyValue != null && String.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyValue.ToString()))
                validPropertyValues++;
        }

        // Check if the minimum allowed is exceeded
        if (MinimumAmount != -1 && validPropertyValues < MinimumAmount)
            return new ValidationResult($"You are required to fill in a minimum of {MinimumAmount} fields.");

        // Check if the maximum allowed is exceeded
        else if (MaximumAmount != -1 && validPropertyValues > MaximumAmount)
            return new ValidationResult($"You can only fill in {MaximumAmount} of fields");

        // 
        else
            return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        ModelClientValidationRule rule = new ModelClientValidationRule();

        rule.ErrorMessage = "Enter your error message here or manipulate it on the client side";
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("minimum", MinimumAmount);
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("maximum", MaximumAmount);
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("properties", string.Join(",", Properties));

        rule.ValidationType = type;

        yield return rule;
    }
}
```

And you use it like this on your class/viewmodel:

```
public class Person
{
    [OptionalRequired(new string[] { nameof(MobileNumber), nameof(LandLineNumber), nameof(FaxNumber) }, MinimumAmount = 2)]
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
    public string LandLineNumber { get; set; }
    public string FaxNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Using this configuration you would need to fill in at least 2 of the required fields otherwise an error will be shown.
You could put the attribute on every property so that the error message pops up on all of them. It is what you want

For client validation I added the interface on the attribute and setup the different parameters but the JavaScript itself I do not have. You would need to look it up (example [here](http://www.macaalay.com/2014/02/24/unobtrusive-client-and-server-side-age-validation-in-mvc-using-custom-data-annotations/) )

This code is not tested but I think it can give you a good idea of how things are done.

Answer (score -1):

```cs
public class MyModel : IValidatableObject
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required!");
    public string PhoneHome{ get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required!");
    public string PhoneWork{ get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required!");
    public string PhoneMobile { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {

        if ((PhoneHome+PhoneWork+PhoneMobile).Length < 1)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("You should set up any phone number!", new [] { "ConfirmForm" });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will try it, but does it work on client side by using the code in my question?

Comment: It seems to be work and makes `ModelState.IsValid` `false` in the Controller. But I do not catch the error message ("You should set up any phone number!") in ModelState. Any idea? Voted up...

Comment: On the other hand in this scenario `[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required!");` parts should be removed from all of the 3 phone properties. Is that true?

Comment: Sure, you should remove Required attributes from the fields.